# Is there an alternative use for python constantly refreshing if values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to place these codes in multiple places. That means a lot of data and workload. What can I do?

Note: ytarihi is a 0 or 1 user's int input.

```
if ytarihi == '2025':
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/label[6]/img').click() 
if ytarihi == '2024':
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/label[7]/img').click() 
if ytarihi == '2023':
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/label[8]/img').click() 
if ytarihi == '2022':
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/label[9]/img').click()
if ytarihi == '2021':
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/label[10]/img').click()
if ytarihi == '2020':
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/label[11]/img').click()    
if ytarihi == '2020':
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/label[11]/img').click()
if ytarihi == '2019':
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/label[12]/img').click()   
if ytarihi == '2018':
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/label[13]/img').click()
if ytarihi == '2017':
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/label[14]/img').click()  
if ytarihi == '2016':
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/label[15]/img').click()  
if ytarihi == '2015':
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/label[16]/img').click() 
if ytarihi == '2014':
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/label[17]/img').click() 
if ytarihi == '2013':
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/label[18]/img').click() 
if ytarihi == '2012':
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/label[19]/img').click() 
if ytarihi == '2011':
    browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/label[20]/img').click()
```

...

These codes repeat until 1980.

Comment: Why not just a dictionary mapping year to index?!

Comment: Doesn't look like you even need a mapping: `index = 2031 - ytarihi` seems to hold.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that label will just keep increasing as we decrease the year, in which case you can just use a for loop to iterate through.

```py
for year in range(2025, 1979, -1):
        path = '//*[@id="content"]/div/form/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/label[{label:d}]/img'
        if ytarihi == str(year):
            browser.find_element_by_xpath(path.format(label=str(2031-i)))
```

Comment: This is essentially iterating over a range to find if one value equals a second.